# alembic autogenerate get the metadata for a Flask-SQLAlchemy bind

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

My flask application has a single database(db1) before, now I bind a new database(db2) to it, both has 10 tables.

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://root@localhost:3306/db1'

SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    'test':    'mysql+pymysql://root@localhost:3306/db2'
}


db = SQLAlchemy()

class table1(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
.......
class table10(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)

class table11(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'db2'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
......
class table20(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'db2'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
```

I want to use alembic autogenerate function to auto detecting and generating migrations for db 1 and db2 separately, but `db.metadata` will get all tables metadata, but how to just get bind db metadata?

---

Thanks @davidism help! I can use include_symbol to make it.

```
def include_symbol(tablename, schema):
    return tablename in ('table1', 'table2'.......'table10') # for db1
    　# return tablename  not in ('table1', 'table2'.......'table10') # for db2

with connectable.connect() as connection:
    context.configure(
        connection=connection,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        include_symbol=include_symbol
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't because that feature doesn't exist yet.  Currently, there is one metadata instance for all models across all binds.  As long as all the models have unique names, this isn't a huge problem.

When we apply [this patch](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/pull/222) and make a new release, each bind will have its own metadata.  You will then be able to access it with `db.get_metadata(bind='db2')`.